# Returning an image into imageView from Google Places Photo JSON

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-places-api, google-places

I'm looking to get the photos from the Google places API, and have them store into a URL or Image to be displayed to the user in a seperate view controller.

It appears the photo json returns this for each location:

```
    photos =  (
                {
                   height = 466;
                   "html_attributions" = ();
                   "photo_reference" = "CnRnAAAAgBUy_mqt9WglYJvS2v8XBfw5ER1U8Wn7DWvfoWI4P78w8_ZAsLQeFSYescNYE1NVgkV50jJE7SYBxdZuOmGP4jWGyCLobCd2nyEDbeB9lg1JU7KYV0o57i-OQTROIwj9ZwzWG03aUOypMjA_7fXD8BIQqbC5J0daROt_LqztWmz-xhoU20meJb50VyAE-zqkp9Jzu1Fegfs";
                   width = 695;
                }
             );
```

And according to Google Places Photo docs all it says:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos

Cannot find an example to be able to take this from json, and store it like I am strings since the url isn't a direct link to an image or anything.

EDIT: Getting error

```
[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13258510
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13258510'
```

Updated Code:

```
-(void)plotPositions:(NSArray *)data {

    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in _mapView.annotations) {
        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapPoint class]]) {
            [_mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
        }
    }
    //  Loop through the array of places returned from the Google API.
    for (int i=0; i<[data count]; i++) {

        NSDictionary* place = [data objectAtIndex:i];

        NSDictionary *geo = [place objectForKey:@"geometry"];

        NSDictionary *loc = [geo objectForKey:@"location"];

        // Getting Photo Reference Details - ADDED NOW RECIEVING ERROR?
        NSDictionary *photoDict = [place objectForKey:@"photos"];
        NSString *photoRef = [photoDict objectForKey:@"photo_reference"];

         NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=%@&key=%@&sensor=false&maxwidth=320", photoRef, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];

        NSLog(@"TESTING: %@", url);


        NSString *name=[place objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *vicinity=[place objectForKey:@"vicinity"];


        CLLocationCoordinate2D placeCoord;
        placeCoord.latitude=[[loc objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        placeCoord.longitude=[[loc objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];

        MapPoint *placeObject = [[MapPoint alloc] initWithName:name address:vicinity rating:rating coordinate:placeCoord];

        [_mapView addAnnotation:placeObject];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photo_reference attribute in the JSON is a parameter that you then use as a parameter to place a Photo Request.

In url you referenced (https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos) specifically look at the section "Place Photo Requests" on the correct way to actually construct the url that will request the image.

Based on your code above, you aren't handling the array of photos returned.  Assuming you want the first photo:

```
NSDictionary *photoDict = [[place objectForKey:@"photos"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *photoRef = [photoDict objectForKey:@"photo_reference"];

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=%@&key=%@&sensor=false&maxwidth=320", photoRef, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];
```

Comment: Okay I ended up doing something similar to what you said but now I'm getting an error. 

Just updated code

Comment: Updated my answer, you need to handle the array of photos

Answer (score 0):

To get the url for the image, you'll need to request it using a request that they call "Photo Request". It's very simple to use, you'll need to pass the photo reference into your url.
Example url with a photo ref.

**NOTE**
Each key is seperated by a "&"

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CoQBegAAAFg5U0y-iQEtUVMfqw4KpXYe60QwJC-wl59NZlcaxSQZNgAhGrjmUKD2NkXatfQF1QRap-PQCx3kMfsKQCcxtkZqQ&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Required parameters

```
key — Your application's API key. This key identifies your application for purposes of quota management. Visit the APIs Console to create an API Project and obtain your key.
photoreference — A string identifier that uniquely identifies a photo. Photo references are returned from either a Place Search or Place Details request.
sensor — Indicates whether or not the Place Photo request came from a device using a location sensor (e.g. a GPS). This value must be either true or false.
maxheight or maxwidth — Specifies the maximum desired height or width, in pixels, of the image returned by the Place Photos service. If the image is smaller than the values specified, the original image will be returned. If the image is larger in either dimension, it will be scaled to match the smaller of the two dimensions, restricted to its original aspect ratio. Both the maxheight and maxwidth properties accept an integer between 1 and 1600.
```

**Update** Give this code a run.

```
-(void)plotPositions:(NSArray *)data {

for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in _mapView.annotations) {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapPoint class]]) {
        [_mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
    }
}
//  Loop through the array of places returned from the Google API.
for (int i=0; i<[data count]; i++) {

    NSDictionary* place = [data objectAtIndex:i];

    NSDictionary *geo = [place objectForKey:@"geometry"];

    NSDictionary *loc = [geo objectForKey:@"location"];

    // Getting Photo Reference Details - ADDED NOW RECIEVING ERROR?
    NSArray *allPhotosDictionaries = [place objectForKey:@"photos"];
    NSDictionary *photoDict;
    if (allPhotosDictionaries.count > 0) {
        photoDict = [allPhotosDictionaries objectAtIndex:0];

    }else {
        photoDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

    }

    NSString *photoRef = [photoDict objectForKey:@"photo_reference"];

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=%@&key=%@&sensor=false&maxwidth=320", photoRef, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];

    NSLog(@"TESTING: %@", url);


    NSString *name=[place objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *vicinity=[place objectForKey:@"vicinity"];


    CLLocationCoordinate2D placeCoord;
    placeCoord.latitude=[[loc objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
    placeCoord.longitude=[[loc objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];

    MapPoint *placeObject = [[MapPoint alloc] initWithName:name address:vicinity rating:rating coordinate:placeCoord];

    [_mapView addAnnotation:placeObject];
}
}
```

Comment: Did what you've instructed but now getting another error, please check updated code

Comment: Ok, so the error is saying that you are trying to call objectForKey on an NSArray. NSArray can't respond to objectForKey, that's a method for an NSDictionary. What that means. Somewhere you defined a dictionary as a NSArray, and then called objectForKey. You just need to change this NSDictionary to an array.

Comment: Okay btu if I were to change the photoDict to an array, I won't be able to take out the photo_reference with "        NSString *photoRef = [photoDict objectForKey:@"photo_reference"];
" because objectForKeys are called on dictionaries..and that is the line that's causing the crash for some reason...I'm doing the same thing I thought I did for geo and loc dictionaries.

Comment: Try changing it to an array of dictionaries. This is in case there are multiple photos.

Comment: Darn wish I would of saw this 10 minutes ago before I saw the other gentlemans update. Sorry I can't Up you too... but your code is similar and works actually better with your conditional check. Thanks again for all your hard work and help

Comment: Glad I could help. Even just a vote up would be appreciated! I understand you already gave the other user a green check

Comment: I will for sure when I get 15 rep, it won't let me until I do unfortunately, sorry!